# I cannot log into the Minecraft launcher

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, pc

I can't log into the Minecraft launcher, because it tells me that the username or passowrd is incorrect. I have tried resetting my password and have even given the account to my freidn and he was able to sign in perfectly, i cannot. If I try to login in through the official website the login button just doesn't simply doesn't work. I have even tried waiting to login in later, restarting my computer, but it hasn't worked. I have used my email and username to login. I have contacted Minecraft support via email and it told me that it is currently reviewing cases for the 30th of April, so I'd  rather try to fix the issue here. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Just for completions sake. Press the Minecraft authenticator button as you did